# how can i make PHP to display pictures

Tags: php, html

I need help to display all my pictures in my folder in a row, not over each other.

```
<?php

$files = glob("bilder/*.*");

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)    
{

    $image = $files[$i];
    $supported_file = array(
                            'gif',
                            'jpg',
                            'jpeg',
                             'png'
                           );

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image .'" width="400" height="500" />'."<br /><br />";
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: remove `<br>` add `style="display:inline-block;"`

Comment: PHP doesnt do this. Its all HTML/CSS

Comment: why are you adding `<br>` tags in your HTML?

Comment: try new line "\n" instead of breaks, but ofcourse this is best done with css by assigning and id to each image for example.

Comment: You really need to look up some CSS, `width="400" height="500"` are so last century man

Comment: BTW, this PHP code is just as "last century"... `continue` at the end of a loop? Re-initialise *$supported_file* in every iteration? Using `for` instead of `foreach($files as $image)`? This could be written in such nice compact code...

Comment: Can you include an image of what you see in the output and don't like?

Comment: Do you mean with *"display all my pictures [...] not over each other"* that the images currently overlap? Or do you mean that they appear in one column, each one below the previous one?

Comment: Well, I assume your silence means your problem is not that important :) I am moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use css classes and styles.

```
echo '<img src="'.$image .'" class="someClass" />';
```

Then include your stylesheet in html head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
```

and finally style your images in that stylesheet.css

```
.someClass{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

All of this is the most basic html and css stuff. Please consider reading some tutorials before asking questions.

Comment: @spero then you have not done it right or haven't looked it up enough. If you want you can upload your files to pastebin and I'll have a look

Comment: php code: http://pastebin.com/hJWFxGvV

and

CSS code: http://pastebin.com/MnuZMN9A

Comment: @spero I especially need the html (at least extracts) since this is where you include the stylesheet/style

Comment: this is my HTML code: http://pastebin.com/EEhLugUg
here I use a PHP that ads the same basic code too all my site.

Comment: @spero try adding a unit to width and height, like `width:150px`

Comment: @spero consider trincot's answer, it has useful advice. Remember to mark whatever answer helps you most as the right one with the check mark at the left

Answer (score 0):

Without any other HTML, images display in-line by default. But the breaks you added with `"<br /><br />"`, nullify this behaviour, and make the images wrap into one column.

So just remove those breaks. If your concern was to wrap the HTML code itself, then insert a newline character (`\n`) instead.

I take the opportunity to highlight some aspects of your PHP code that could be improved:

- there is no use in doing `continue;` when that is the last statement of the loop. You can just leave that `else` block out;
- PHP has a nice construct for looping over an array, i.e. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). It makes the code more compact while improving the readability at the same time;
- You initialise the variable *$supported_file* to the same value in every iteration of the loop: this should happen outside the loop;
- to filter an array of file names, you can use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php);
- as HTML supports single quotes as value delimiters and PHP will expand variable names in double quotes, you get (in my opinion) nicer code by switching the use of double/single quotes.

This clean-up results in this code:

```
$files = preg_grep('/^.*\.gif|jpg|jpeg|png$/i', glob("bilder/*.*"));
foreach ($files as $image) {
    echo "<img src='$image' width='400' height='500'/>\n";
}
```

Concerning the HTML attributes `width` and `height` applied on images:

This really is something to avoid. You should instead use the proper dimensions of those images, as the images risk to get ugly by forcing a size upon them. If they are your images, then make those images to have the right size. I have kept those attributes in the above code, but please reconsider how you deal with image sizes.

I noticed also an issue in the HTML you shared on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/EEhLugUg):

- The `title` and `meta` tags should be moved in the `head` tag, they are not supposed to appear as direct children of the `html` tag.
- Note also that you have a background image loaded via the `body` tag. I hope you did not misinterpret that, because surely that image will be overlapped by the other `img` tags you produce.